# meet error when implementing "velodyne_driver" command for vlp-16

Tags: ros, bagfile, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to do as the answer to #q213080 says, but when I try the second command

```
rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _model:=VLP16 _pcap:=/your/pcap/path/data.pcap _read_once:=true
```

It says

```
[ERROR] [1485795341.945746381]: unknown Velodyne LIDAR model: VLP16
```

Does anybody have idea?

[PS] I have git cloned the package from https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne.git and https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne.git and built the workspace as some other guidance says.

---

Edit: @gvdhoorn I think you are right. My initial ouput of it is not this. after I sourced the devel/setup.bash, the first question is solved. Now the response is

```
[FATAL] [1486012428.835246258]: Error opening Velodyne socket dump file.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253321/meet-error-when-implementing-%22velodyne_driver%22-command-for-vlp-16/) by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-01-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-31**:
Can you tell us the output of `rospack find velodyne_driver`?

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-01**:
It returns like

```
/home/wbw/catkin_ws/src/velodyne/velodyne_driver
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-02**:
Just making sure: you did replace `/your/pcap/path/data.pcap` with the actual path to a `pcap` file, right? Do you actually want to use a 'live' lidar, or do you want to open a capture file that you made earlier? If the former, don't use the `_pcap` parameter.

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-02**:
@gvdhoorn I replaced with the actual path to a pcap file like

```
/home/wbw/Downloads/2015-05-29-22-49-14_Velodyne-VLP-16-Data.pcap.
```

This is a capture file and I didn't mean to use live lidar data. Am I doing right?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-02**:
Yes, that sounds ok. I was just making sure, as the command line you included in your OP used an example path, and that would lead to problems.

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-02**:
@gvdhoorn Ok, thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are probably running the Indigo binary version instead of the one you built. Most likely, you forgot to source the `devel/setup.bash` in your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2017-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-01**:
Is there any command to check if mine is "indigo binary version"? I just installed ros by following ros-wiki.

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2017-02-02**:
Use `roscd velodyne_pointcloud` and see if it takes you to `/opt/ros/` or your workspace.
Use `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` to see if your catkin workspace overlay is correctly setup.

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-02**:
@kmhallen The first output is

```
wbw@wbw-virtual-machine:~/catkin_ws/src/velodyne/velodyne_pointcloud$
```

The second output is

```
/home/wbw/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

It seems that the second one is not working well, is that right? I'm new to ros...

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2017-02-03**:
That output looks fine. The second output means: check `/home/wbw/catkin_ws/src` first, then check `/opt/ros/indigo`

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-03**:
@kmhallen @joq  It seems that I need to source devel/setup.bash every time I restart my computer. Is there a way to solve it permanently?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-02-04**:
If you only use one workspace, you can source it from your `~/.bashrc`. For people with multiple workspaces  that leads to confusion. I prefer to define short aliases (like `ws`) that each run an appropriate `source` command.

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-04**:
@joq Thanks, it works! But do you know the solution to my question?

```
[FATAL] [1486012428.835246258]: Error opening Velodyne socket dump file.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-02-04**:
Don't know for sure. Perhaps you did not pass the full file name path? (That still should not segfault).